# Mongodb - list only certain attributes combined with selected id

Tags: mongodb, attributes, document

Im trying to list only the first name, surname, age and sex where the id is between 101 and 107.  I can get each part of the query to run but having trouble combining them.  This is my code:

`db.users.find({$and: [{_id:{$gt: 100, $lt:108}},{_id:0, fname:1, surname:1, age:1, Sex:1}]})`

But when I hit return the cursor just blinks like its waiting for something else from me.  I suppose what Im asking is what am I doing wrong and how do I combine these two so I dont make the same error in future.

`db.users.find({_id:{$gt: 100, $lt:108}})` works for me

`db.users.find({_id:{$gt: 100, $lt:108}})` also works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is just a little off and Mongo is fails in parsing the query.

Try this:

```
db.users.find({_id: { $gt: 100, $lt:108}}, {_id:0, fname:1, surname:1, age:1, Sex:1})
```

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I was over complicating it. I was under the impression that " $and"   had to be used when I was joining queries.